# Computing slope using QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, slope

I want to compute the TWI (Topographic Wetness Index) for my study zone (SZ) using a DEM that I reduced to my SZ (SZ_DEM, https://www.mediafire.com/file/46vr8r4pbl2vpol/SZ_DEM.tif/file).

The first step is to compute the slope but I've some issues doing that. Almost every pixel is 89.9… degree and few equal to 0.

I tried to find solution online. One of them was to project my layer and my project for the UTM of my zone (51 S). So I try with changing both layer and project CRS (EPSG 32751). But it doesn't help. I also read that the ellipsoid of my project had to correspond. So I saw it in EPSG 7030 for WGS 84.

So that’s fine right?

And I changed the units to km² and km.

Is the problem coming from the DEM ?

Is the problem in my projection system or in my project unit or ellipsoid?

Here is the original DEM file : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oZf46TUbaoyN7IrvhOSnL1DwdjDvFFVi/view

Comment: Did you convert the DEM into EPSG:32751 with Reproject layer? If you just changed the CRS code it does not modify the data.

Comment: Maybe you can also share a link to the oridinal DEM (before reducing it to the Study Zone)?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, the input DEM has a wrong underlying CRS.
The whole ratser extends for only about 4 meters North-South, while it should probably measure 4 kilometers (or any other meaningful geographical extension).

[image]

Without knowing anything more, I would suggest to trace back the steps that brought you to the creation of the file you linked, and see where the unit problem occurs.

Comment: And to complicate your problem you should confirm the vertical datum of you surface.  A vertical datum that represent heights above an ellipsoid (and not gravitational heights) may produce odd results with respect to slope.  See this link for more information:  https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/properties/vertical-datums.htm